# List isnt getting appended with contents of another list in Python

Tags: python

I'm attempting to find specific sections of a list that was pulled from a csv file.  using 2 different functions. I don't know what the issue is but the return value is blank.

```
def find_flight(filename, airlines, city, earliest, latest):
    mf = []
    lf = []
    mf = get_filtered_CSV(filename, airlines)
    for row in mf:
        if mf[1] == city:
            if latest > mf[2] >= earliest:
                lf.append(row)
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    return lf
```

//

```
def get_filtered_CSV(filename, filter_by):
    lst = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(myfile)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row[0] == filter_by:
                lst.append(row)
    return lst

print(find_flight("Airport.csv", "United", "Portland", "0000", "2400"))
```

Comment: Which return value? `lf` or `lst`?

Comment: try printing `print(latest > mf[2] >= earliest)` and see if this is ever true. Then start seeing why if this is not true, but is expected to be true

Comment: What does the data look like in the csv file ? And give us an example of how you are calling the find_flight(...) function

Comment: the lf return value @mkrieger1

Comment: @Chinny84: Almost certainly that `print` would die with a `TypeError` (because `mf[2]` is a `list`). The `mf[1] == city` test should reliably return `False` (because `mf[1]` is also a `list`, while `city` is a `str`).

Comment: was not really checking the details of the `if` statement, I was assuming that this would have been flagged in the original question. I was just trying to get the OP to debug the places which would prevent the lists being populated. But fair point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `find_flight`, your loop never uses the `row` iteration variable except to `append` it if the other tests pass. *All* your tests are based on `mf` (the `list` of `list`s you're iterating over), which does not change from loop to loop. So instead of comparing specific scalar values from each row to other scalar values (`str`), you're comparing the second row as a whole (the entire `list`) to a single scalar value (`city`, a `str`) and making a similar mistake comparing the third row as a whole to `earliest` and `latest`. Those uses of `mf` (the outer `list`) should in fact refer to `row` (the `list` for that particular row of data), replacing:

```
for row in mf:
    if mf[1] == city:
        if latest > mf[2] >= earliest:
            lf.append(row)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

with (also removing the pointless `else: pass`es that serve no purpose):

```
for row in mf:
    if row[1] == city:  # row[1], not mf[1]
        if latest > row[2] >= earliest:  # row[2], not mf[2]
            lf.append(row)
```

or combining the tests into one `if`:

```
for row in mf:
    if row[1] == city and latest > row[2] >= earliest:
        lf.append(row)
```

The reason this was *silently* appending nothing is the `mf[1] == city` test; `mf[1]` is a sub-`list`, and you're comparing it to a `str`, and that comparison will *always* be `False`. If the code had reached the `latest > mf[2] >= earliest` test, you'd've gotten a `TypeError` (because a failure to implement `>` or `>=` raises `TypeError` rather than silently returning `True` or `False`), but the first test prevents you from getting that far.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the index as *0* because it might be considering 0^th index of the string.
In the function `get_filtered_CSV`

update     `if row[0] == filter_by:`
to     `if row == filter_by:`

Comment: get_filtered_CSV is working as intended its find_flight that isnt working.  I tried your suggestion anyways and it does the same thing.